# VBA error 1004 and source file become read only

Tags: excel, vba, readonly

I am trying to read two pages ("SYN" and "STR") of an excel file into two different arrays.

the code is very simple, and it works just fine if i only need one page :

```
Sub recap()
Dim wb As Workbook  
Dim fpath As String
fpath = Application.ActiveProject.Path & "\Suivi d'études.xlsm"  
'(this is the file I want to read in the same folder)

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fpath, True, False)

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim i, j As Integer

i = wb.Worksheets("STR").UsedRange.Rows.Count
j = wb.Worksheets("STR").Columns.Count

Set rng1 = wb.Worksheets("STR").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(i, j))

Dim data2(), data1() As Variant
data1() = rng1

wb.Close

Debug.Print (data1(10, 10))

End Sub
```

it works just fine. 
Then I intergrated the seconde page.

```
Sub recap()

Dim wb As Workbook   'Need Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
Dim fpath As String
fpath = Application.ActiveProject.Path & "\Suivi d'études.xlsm"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fpath, True, False)

Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
Dim i, j, a, b As Integer

a = wb.Worksheets("SYN").UsedRange.Rows.Count
b = wb.Worksheets("SYN").Columns.Count

i = wb.Worksheets("STR").UsedRange.Rows.Count
j = wb.Worksheets("STR").Columns.Count

Set rng1 = wb.Worksheets("SYN").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(a, b))
Set rng2 = wb.Worksheets("STR").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(i, j))

Dim data2(), data1() As Variant
data1() = rng1
data2() = rng2
wb.Close
Debug.Print (data2(10, 10))
End Sub
```

Not only it gaves me 1004 error on the range setting line: set rng1 = blablabla, but also since the code is not fully executed, the input excel file is still "open" in the code, it became a read-only file.

So my questions are: 
1. which could cause this error, why can't they read the seconde page in an array? 
2. how to force the input file to "close" if wb.close was not executed?

Comment: you need to qualify your `Cells` references too using your `wb` object, as they are referring to the `ActiveSheet` without a qualifier. Your first example must work because your `wb` is the `ActiveSheet` - those should be qualified too or they too will be prone to error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to define your variables properly. When you do `Dim rng1, rng2 As Range`, only `rng2` is being defined as `Range`. Variable `rng1` is being defined as `Variant`, so Excel thinks you are trying to take into an array when you do `Set rng1 = wb.Worksheets("SYN").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(a, b))` and `Set` is not for variables, only for objects. Try `Dim rng1 as Range, rng2 As Range`

Comment: As braX said you need to use explicit references to the `cells` like so `wb.Worksheets("SYN").cells()`. Also when you declare multiple variables in a single line you have to do it like `Dim rng1 as Range, rng2 As Range`, otherwise only the last one is declared correctly and the rest are declared as variants.

Comment: Thanks guys.   oh, god, I've been using the wrong way to define my variables since one year. @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns.

Comment: @ShengweiLi Nice! I'll post it as answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is how you define your variables. In your first code you did:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
'
'
'
Set rng1 = wb.Worksheets("STR").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(i, j))
```

Because `rng1` has been created as a `Range Object`, yes, you need to set it up with `Set`.

In your second code you did:

```
Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
'
'
'
'
Set rng1 = wb.Worksheets("SYN").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(a, b))
Set rng2 = wb.Worksheets("STR").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(i, j))
```

Notice that only `rng2` is being defined as a `Range Object`. Variable `rng1` is being defined as `Variant`, the default option in VBA when you don't specify a type.

So VBA thinks `rng1` is a `Variant` and then later on you do:

```
Set rng1 = wb.Worksheets("SYN").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(a, b))
```

And that raises an error because `Set` must be used only with objects.

VBA, because `rng1` has been defined as `Variant`, was expecting a line like:

`rng1 = wb.Worksheets("SYN").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(a, b))`

This means you are taking all those values in that range into a **bidimensional** array named `rng1`. You don't want to do this, but this explains why VBA raises that error.

The solution is really easy. Just define **always** what type of variables/objects you are using.

Line `Dim rng1 as Range, rng2 As Range` should fix your problem. Always declare properly all your variables.

Hope this helps.